# Matrix of adjoint linear map is transposed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, transpose

I am stuck with some exercise and hope that someone can give me a hint:

---

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and let $B_V = \big\{ v_1, \ldots, v_n \big\}$ and $B_w = \big\{ w_1, \ldots, w_n \big\}$ be bases of $V$ and of $W$.

> Let furthermore be $\big\{ \alpha^1, \ldots, \alpha^n \big\}$ be the dual basis of $B_V$ and let $\big\{ \beta^1, \ldots, \beta^n \big\}$ be the dual basis of $B_W$.

> Let $\varphi : V \longrightarrow W$ be a linear map and let $A^i{}_j$ be its matrix representation with respect to the bases $B_V$ and $B_W$. Show that the matrix representation of the adjoint map $\varphi^{\ast} : W^{\ast} \longrightarrow V^{\ast}$ is the transpose of $(A^i{}_j)^T$.

---

I cannot quite close the proof for this. My attempt is as follows:

**1.** Let $\varphi(X) = Y$, then

$$ \beta^i(Y) = \beta^i(Y^j w_j ) = Y^j \beta^i(w_j) = Y^j \delta^i_j = Y^i $$

and therefore

$$Y^i = \beta^i(Y) = \beta^i \big( \varphi(X) \big) = X^j \beta^i \big( \varphi(v_j) \big)$$

Consequently, the matrix representation of $\varphi$ in said bases is

$$ A^i{}_j = \beta^i \big( \varphi( v_j ) \big)$$

${}$

**2.** Now, doing an analogous calculation yields the following: Let $\Psi = \varphi^{\ast}(\Omega)$, then

$$ \Psi(v_i) = \big( \Psi_j \alpha^j \big)(v_i) = \Psi_j \alpha^j(v_i) = \Psi_j \delta^j_i = \Psi_i$$

and therefore

$$\Psi_i = \Psi(v_i) = \varphi^{\ast}(\Omega)(v_i) = \varphi^{\ast} \big( \Omega_j \beta^j \big) (v_i) = \Omega_j \, \varphi^{\ast}(\beta^j)(v_i) $$

and consequently the matrix representation $C^i{}_j$ of $\varphi^{\ast}$ with respect to the considered dual bases is

$$C^j{}_i = \varphi^{\ast}(\beta^j)(v_i)$$.

${}$

**3.** The adjoint map is defined as

$$\varphi^{\ast}(\Omega)(X) = \Omega \big( \varphi(X) \big) \quad , \qquad \text{for some} \enspace \Omega \in W^{\ast} , X \in V$$

and so

$$C^j{}_i = \varphi^{\ast}(\beta^j)(v_i) = \beta^j \big( \varphi(v_i) \big) = A^j{}_i$$

---

What am I missing here? The transposed matrix of $A^i{}_j$ is supposed to be $A_j{}^i$. This is however not my result here. Can anyone help me find and correct my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've just made a mistake in part 2. I'm not used to the notation you're using, but I'll try to keep it the same (so if something is off in my notation let me know). I'm going to use lower case letters for the matrix entries though.

In your part 1 you get $a^i_j=\beta^i(\varphi(v_j))=\varphi^*(\beta^i)(v_j)$, which is correct. A way to think about this is the following. The map $\varphi$ sends $v_j$ to $\sum_l a^l_j w_l$, i.e. $a^i_j$ is the $i$-th coordinate of $\varphi(v_j)$ with respect to the $B_W$ basis. But, by definition of dual basis, $\beta^i$ picks out the $i$-th coordinate of a vector in $W$ with respect to the $B_W$ basis. So $$\beta^i(\varphi(v_j))=\text{$i$-th coordinate of $\varphi(v_j)$}=a^i_j.$$

Now let's apply this approach to $\varphi^*$. If $C$ is the matrix, then $\varphi^*$ sends $\beta^i$ to $\sum_l c^l_i \alpha^l$, i.e. $c^j_i$ is the $j$-th coordinate of $\varphi^*(\beta^i)$ with respect to the dual basis $B_V^*$. That is, $$\varphi^*(\beta^i)=\sum_l c^l_i\alpha^l.$$

Let's evaluate both sides of the above at $v_j$:
$$(LHS):\quad \varphi^*(\beta^i)(v_j)=a^i_j$$
$$(RHS):\quad \sum_l c^l_i\alpha^l(v_j) = \sum_l c^l_i \delta^l_j = c^j_i.$$

Comparing the above we get $a^i_j=c^j_i$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I think a small error occured within it. In the sentence "[...] If $C$ is the matrix, then $\varphi^{\ast}$ sends $\beta^i$ to $\sum_l c^l_i \alpha_l$ [...]" you are indexing $\alpha$ by down-indices. Since $\alpha$ is the dual basis to $v$ it should be indexed with up-indices, shouldn't it?

If $\alpha$ would be indexed that way, then the last two equations combined would read

$$a^i_j = c^i_j$$

which is again my initial problem.

Comment: P.S.: I updated the question so to include calculation in point **2.**

Comment: I did mean to write $\alpha^l$, thanks. I'll edit it. Although this indexing doesn't really matter, you could just denote it as $\alpha_l$ (this is the notation I would use, hence my preamble).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid I still don't quite understand it. What bothers me, is that - when using summation convention - the equation for $\varphi^{\ast}(\beta^i)$ should rather look something like

$$\varphi^{\ast}(\beta^i) = c^i_l \alpha^l$$

Instead of

$$\varphi^{\ast}(\beta^i) = c^l_i \alpha^l$$

I don't know how to connect your version to my version.

Comment: I was assuming that the superscript represents the row and the subscript represents the column. So in the sums that I have we want to sum along the rows.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your answer and your time!